# Correct way to filter out built in AD SecurityGroups

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a LDAP searchquery where i am using the following filter

```
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"
```

and running against AD in order to get User-accounts out. One of the attributes being returned ("memberOf") holds a ";" separated string of groups that user is a member of.

i.e.

CN=MyGroup,OU=MyMainOU,DC=masterdom,DC=local;
CN=Administrators,**CN=Builtin**,DC=masterdom,DC=local

I want to filter out the BuiltIn security groups, when processing the list can I rely on the "built in" groups containing the string "cn=builtin"? Or could it change with local etc. If so what is the correct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You if want to utilize the `memberOf` attribute, you can include it in your filter by using the full container name :

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(memberof=CN=Builtin,DC=masterdom,DC=local))
```

Something to keep in mind though, is that the `memberOf` attribute will only show groups native to the domain component (DC) in which the user is derived from - by that I mean, if user `A` is part of both the `Developers` and `Management` groups, but the `Developers` group doesn't exist within the current domain component you're querying, then the `memberOf` attribute will only show the `Management` group for the user when queried.

Plus, the `memberOf` attribute is a *computed back-link attribute* or a *constructed attribute*. It's maintained and calculated by Active Directory, so as you move users and groups around, that value will automatically change for the user.

However, judging by your post, if you're just iterating through a list of users and checking the `memberOf` attributes for the existence of `CN=Builtin` (ex. a `.Contains` check), then yes, you can rely on that string being there, given it's part of the DC you're querying.

Comment: I don't think this will work. CN=Builtin,DC=masterdom,DC=local is a container not a group.